# Why doesn't this stack have a cool background and things other stacks has?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was going through the other stacks and found those stacks more eye-catching and visually attractive . May it be the background or the icons. It was put well . This site does represent **MANGA** and **ANIME** right? So why does this stack have the basic design? I don't care if i get Voted down on this . This stack would look fab if the details got right . Cheerio :)

Comment: +1, I was about to ask the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the layout and design of the home page looks a bit dull compared to other Stack Exchange websites?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4033/why-does-the-layout-and-design-of-the-home-page-looks-a-bit-dull-compared-to-oth)

Answer (score 4):

That's because the site is still in beta (notice the *beta* next to the Anime & Manga logo?). The site is in queue for graduation, and will get a proper design when it graduates (or rather, it will graduate once a proper design is made for it ;)

Comment: Ohh .. nice .. what does it take for this stack to graduate ? I mean who are the guys responsible for the proper design development?

Comment: There are several criteria (which we all pass), we're just waiting on design for now. You can read more about the Stack Exchange process on [area51.se]'s FAQ.

Comment: Gotcha boss :) . Hope it happens soon :D