# Why does the layout and design of the home page looks a bit dull compared to other Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, design

This may seem as a pointless question to many, but I'm new here and just wanted to know a bit more about the Stack Exchange websites. While visiting various other Stack Exchange websites, I noticed that the top of the home page over there looks far more attractive than the one on this website :

[image: SF&F's design]

[image: Chemistry's design]

[image: Puzzling's design]

[image: Physics's design]

## But when you look at this website:

[image: Anime's design]

There is an obvious difference. Why is this site not made as attractive as the other sites. I'm guessing its probably because of the lack of popularity, but come on. We're pretty popular (We as in this community). Also, Who decides this stuff ? I was curious about that. And if this question is irrelevant to this website or cannot be answered, just let me know and I'll delete it myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All Stack Exchange sites start out [in "beta"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) and look the way ours does. After a site achieves sufficient activity, it ["graduates"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/). It used to be that graduation was always accompanied by snazzy designs like the ones you've posted, but [that changed about two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/) so that getting a snazzy design comes some time after graduation.

Our site has graduated (so, for example, you don't see "beta" in our site header like you would on, say, [Alcohol.SE](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/)), but does not yet have a design. Creating a new design for a Stack Exchange site is a labor-intensive process, and Stack Overflow (the company) has only limited resources. We are somewhere in the queue for getting a design - it'll happen eventually.

We are a reasonably popular site compared to Stack Exchange as a whole, but if you go to http://stackexchange.com/sites and sort by whatever metric you'd like, you'll see that there are sites that are more active than us that also don't have a design (you can tell because their icons are generic blue speech bubbles).

Comment: I'll be waiting for a nice design. And thanks for answering : )

Comment: Given more recent information, I'm no longer sure that "it'll happen eventually" is the official stance. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/ suggests that the new requirement for a design is "10 questions per day", which we have not come close to since removing ID requests. Other posts have suggested that a lot more sites may have the "beta" label removed in the near future without getting site designs, and we may be retroactively moved in that group. So it seems consistent with that information that we may no longer be in the queue to get a design in the future.

Comment: @LoganM You raise a good point. Our questions/day has been hovering around 5-7 for about a year now, so in that sense, I agree that at this moment, we do not meet all the criteria for getting a design. However, many of our other site metrics (page views, new registrations, anonymous feedback) have been steadily rising over the past 6-12 months, so I'm inclined to suspect that our current low questions/day is a transient phenomenon that should resolve itself eventually and put us back up above 10 questions/day.

Comment: Side note: some sites, like TCS.SE or the various CRM sites, are intrinsically limited in the number of questions/day they can receive by the nature of their subject matter. The "intrinsic" limit on the number of anime & manga questions that can be asked per day is probably somewhere well above 10/day, so I'm not worried about us being saturated just yet.

Comment: Relevant context: [*The last time a site design went live: October 5, 2016... That was Signal Processing.*](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5947471#5947471) and [*Sites which have graduated but not yet get site design: Quant, Mechanics, Law, Philosophy, Codegolf, Anime.*](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5947469#5947469)

Answer (score 3):

*Adding an answer here because the current one is outdated and the answer is kinda obvious:*

This Stack's design went live in [July 2019](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4272/42482), after [having graduated in 2015](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2594/42482).