# Please remove the white outline on the hat in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The hat in chat has a white border around it. Much [like it did on Meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274).

Please can these white lines be removed.

[image: Image of hat with white outline.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! The chat hat asset has been updated with one that works on any background. You may still see the old image for up to 7 days while it is cached.

|  | Old | New |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Normal | [image: The old chat hat resource on a blue background with the white outlines barely visible.] | [image: The chat new hat resource on a blue background with no white outlines.] |
| Zoomed In | [image: The old chat hat resource zoomed in on a blue background with the white outlines more pronounced.] | [image: The new chat hat resource zoomed in on a blue background with no white outlines.] |