# Does this hat belong to the protagonist of Lucy-May of the Southern Rainbow?

Tags: discussion

On the main page of the site, there's this hat on the left side:

[image]

Does it belong to the protagonist of Japanese anime *Lucy-May of the Southern Rainbow*?

[image]

Comment: Well, unless the designer themselves answer it, I don't think this can be answered by us the community... and even then, [the artist was commissioned](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4272/2516), not from SE internal designer team.

Comment: I've always assumed it was Luffy's straw hat from One Piece. The hat in your image is tall and cylinder shaped whereas Luffy's is short and round, just like the one in the site theme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see Lucy-May's hat, [Wondercricket sees Luffy's hat](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4424/does-this-hat-belong-to-the-protagonist-of-lucy-may-of-the-southern-rainbow#comment8955_4424), I see [Sophie's (from Howl's Moving Castle) hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYLuZ.jpg).

I think that was the artist's point here: it's vague but prevalent enough in the anime and manga world that it gives you the right vibe even if not explicitly pointing towards a particular character or piece of work.